# Sequelize Transaction isolation level issue with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js, isolation-level

We have a function which has a Sequelize transaction. Within the transaction, it checks a field on a database table row, and based on that field, it either returns, or continues onto update various database tables.

For example

```
let buyingStatus = await models.buyingFood.findOne({ where: { id: 21 }, transaction: t});
if (buyingStatus.status == 'bought') return 'already bought'
```

If it continues, it updates multiple places, which should only update if the status isn't `bought`, then finally, changes the status to `bought`.

The problem is when the function is called twice, at the same time. The bottleneck is the updates that occur after the select statement. So two people can pass the buying status being not bought, then both update the `bought` status, along with all the other updates.

Not being an expert in SQL, we researched and found that locking the table, or changing the isolation level could fix this. However we implemented both and didnt help. See below

1) Changing Isolation level

```
let t = await models.sequelize.transaction(isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE);
```

2) Setting lock on the find

```
let buyingStatus = await models.buyingFood.findOne({ where: { id: 21 }, transaction: t, lock: t.LOCK.UPDATE });
```

What we want, is to read from uncommitted transactions, so person B is unable commit if person A has changed the `bought` status before him

Answer (score 0):

The reads are fine to run concurrently, it is the different updates that needs to use the same transaction that need to result in a non serializable conflict for an error to occur. So to be able to answer one would need more information, but if both calls result in the same end result, it will not result in a conflict.